# RcppArmadillo: convert sp_mat to sp_imat

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I was reading through [Dirk's notes](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/rcpp_ku_nov2013-part2.pdf) because I was trying to find a solution to passing a sparse matrix to an Rcpp function. My sparse matrix only contains ones and zeros, so I tried the following in order to convert the `sp_mat` object to an `sp_imat` object:

```
arma::sp_imat toSpMat(Rcpp::S4 mat){

  Rcpp::IntegerVector dims = mat.slot("Dim");
  arma::urowvec i = Rcpp::as<arma::urowvec>(mat.slot("i"));
  arma::urowvec p = Rcpp::as<arma::urowvec>(mat.slot("p"));
  arma::vec x = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(mat.slot("x"));
  int nrow = dims[0], ncol = dims[1];
  arma::sp_mat res(i, p, x, nrow, ncol);
  arma::sp_imat res2(res);
  return res2;

}
```

However, initializing `sp_imat` the way I did is not possible. I received the following error:

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'arma::sp_imat' (aka 'SpMat')

I also tried to initialize `sp_imat` using a batch insertion constructor, but that also didn't work. What's the right way to do it? I am trying to make it work with this example:

```
library(Matrix)

> mat = Matrix(c(1,0,0,1), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, sparse = T)
> mat2 = toSpMat(mat)
```

Comment: Not sure -- we may only have sparse _numeric_ matrices.

Comment: I think this might be a surfacing issue ala `// [[Rcpp::export]]`. The converter does not exist to automatically go from `sp_imat` to *R*. What happens if the return type is `void`?

Comment: @Coatless the expression `arma::sp_imat res2(res);` gives an error. Do you have a fix for this conversion?

Comment: @Cauchy: Could you add some sample data to your example?

Comment: @Coatless i just did.

Answer (score 1):

Per [line 93 of RcppArmadilloWrap.h](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/include/RcppArmadilloWrap.h#L93), conversion to integer is commented out.  I do not recall why.

Maybe you can experiment with that; else you may have to use sparse *real* value data points.

*Edit:* A highlighted by @coatless, but you have there is an Armadillo-only programming error.  You need its [`conv_to()` function](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#conv_to).

In a larger sense, as you seem to be writing hand-converters, you may just want to work on the "internal" representation.  After all, the indexing should be the same...

Comment: The change over was [recent as well](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/commit/8041c0314a0b577ba6f6064f6f935ce0b67c09c4) when there were less copies being made...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel ok thanks. What if I don't want to export it, what if I just want to use the output somewhere else in an Rcpp function, this expression still gives an error   `arma::sp_imat res2(res);`

Comment: Three years ago is an interesting definition of recent :)   The 'fewer copies' may have driven it -- I guess we could bite our tongue, copy to int and support it.  Less overall storage at the cost of an extra copy?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel For what I'm using it for, the extra copy overhead is acceptable for the sake of saving a lot of space. Also, I just want to point out that `conv_to` does not work, I tried   `arma::sp_imat res2 = arma::conv_to<arma::sp_imat>::from(res);`, and I get an error: `no matching function for call to "arma::conv_to<arma::SpMat<int>>::from(arma::sp_mat&)"`

Comment: Yup. But @coatless and I noodles over this off-site, and your other issue is that Armadillo does _not_ have a sparse version of `conv_to()`. You may have to go in many small steps from "sparse double" to "dense doube" to "dense int" to "sparse int".  Try that. Otherwise, dig into the Matrix package for R which may have alternate converters.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I don't have enough memory to do this. Basically, all I need to do is take a bitwise or between elements in a `sp_imat` 0-1 matrix, so I think i'll just use `sp_mat` for that, it should be the same result just more memory. Thanks again for looking into this.